# Ruby and mysql2- iterating a subset of rows in result set

Tags: mysql, ruby

I'm writing a Ruby script that accesses a MySQL database using the Mysql2 gem.

After I get a set of results from a query, I want to examine a subset of the rows of the result set (e.g. rows 5 to 8) rather than the whole set.

I know I can do this with a while loop, something like this:

```
db = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "myserver", :username => "user", :password => "pass", :database => "books")

rs = db.query "select * from bookslist"

i = 5
while i <= 8
    puts rs.entries[i]
    i += 1
end

db.close
```

But I'm aware this is probably not the best way to write this in Ruby. How can I make this more "idiomatic" Ruby code?

(I know my other option is to modify the query to return only the data I want. I still want to know how to do this in Ruby)

Answer (score 1):

Ruby provides range operator in for loop, Probably you can use following code

```
for i in 5..8
  puts rs.entries[i]
end
```